# Terminal says Chromium is installed but I can't find it?

Tags: chromium

I tried to install Chromium using `sudo apt-get install chromium-browser` and all seemed to be well but when I went to search the computer to open Chromium I couldn't find it. Went back to the terminal to try it again and I get this:

```
chromium-browser is already the newest version (49.0.2623.108-0ubuntu1.1233).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libandroid-properties1 libedataserverui-1.2-1 liboxideqt-qmlplugin
  liboxideqtcore0 liboxideqtquick0 libqt5positioning5 libwhoopsie-preferences0
  oxideqt-codecs qml-module-qt-labs-folderlistmodel
  qml-module-qt-labs-settings qml-module-ubuntu-onlineaccounts
  qml-module-ubuntu-web qtdeclarative5-accounts-plugin
  qtdeclarative5-qtquick2-plugin unity-webapps-qml whoopsie-preferences
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong?

Update: I had to restart it a couple of times but Chromium appears now, thanks!

Comment: Have you tried logging out and then back in? This may be enough to kick start Dash :)

Answer (score 2):

If simple doing a reboot wont get you the `chromium-browser` in your dash you can as well kick-start it from terminal and at least lock its icon in the launcher. To do so open a terminal (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>) and type:

```
chromium-browser
```

When it is opened you can right-click its icon in the launcher bar and choose `lock to launcher`.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Videonauth's proper answer, you can open the `.desktop` file created for Chromium. Most apps have a "shortcut" ( a `program.desktop` ) file created for them

Open your file manager and navigate to `/usr/share/applications` folder. You will find `chromium-browser.desktop` file, which you then drag to launcher or desktop.

Unity Dash shows those shortcuts , but it has to read them from a database. I have not yet found a way to reload the database manually, but it Unity seems to read it by itself upon re-logging / re-booting.